# parse webpage upto n levels using wget

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, wget

I am trying to extract URLS from a webpage up to user defined n levels using wget. I tried this

```
 wget -r -l$2 --reject=gif -O out.html www.google.com | sed -n 's/.*href="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p'` "
```

It is displaying only the first level. it is not parsing any levels 
how could i rectify it

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the $2 unless you're assigning a variable 2=1 or something like that elsewhere, -l$2 will cause wget to output `wget: --level: Invalid number`  which will not feed into sed very well.

you can do:

```
wget -l 2 <address>
```

or

```
wget --length=2 <address>
```

you may also have interest in the no-parent option, which will prevent wget from traversing up the directory (n levels). This is an especialy  useful option when retrieving recursively, since it guarantees that only the files below a certain hierarchy will  be downloaded.

```
wget -np <address>
```